# jQuery - show/hide based on user input

Tags: php, jquery, show-hide

I have the following `div`'s on my page:

```
<div id="page1">
    Some content
</div>

<div id="page2">
    More content
</div>

<div id="page3">
    Even more content
</div>
```

At the bottom of the page, I have two buttons `Continue` and `Back` - what I need to do is to show and hide the divs based on the users input.

By default `page1` should be shown and the others are hidden, when the users clicks `Continue'`page2`is shown and`pages 1 and 3`are hidden - if the user clicks the`Back`button then`page1` is shown and the others are hidden and so on.

I'm having a complete mental block of how to implement this in jQuery - any and all help welcomed.

Comment: Thank you to everyone who submitted, brilliant stuff.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to place those elements within a container, and then use `prev` and `next` to traverse them. Something like this:

```
$('.next').click(function() {
    $('.sequence-container div').hide();
    var $next = $('.sequence-container div:visible').next();
    $next.length ? $next.show() : $('.sequence-container div:first').show();
});

$('.prev').click(function() {
    $('.sequence-container div').hide();
    var $prev = $('.sequence-container div:visible').prev();
    $prev.length ? $prev.show() : $('.sequence-container div:last').show();
});
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/exU8p/)

---

**UPDATE**

To prevent the looping from start/end use this:

```
$('.next').click(function() {
    var $next = $('.sequence-container div:visible').next();    
    if ($next.length) {
        $('.sequence-container div').hide();
        $next.show();
    }
});

$('.prev').click(function() {
    var $prev = $('.sequence-container div:visible').prev();
    if ($prev.length) {
        $('.sequence-container div').hide();
        $prev.show();
    }
});
```

[**Updated fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/exU8p/1/)

Comment: That looks great, thank you - one final question - how would one stop at the final div in the list and not allow to go further?  At the moment, it just keeps iterating through?

Comment: Check out my answer if you want a code stoping at the final div (But you should specify your number of div at the beggining, i think mine can be improve to stop to the last div without giving him the number of div)

Comment: Thanks Okazari - yours does work a treat - thank you, just checking on this answer to see how easy to implement the stopping at the last div.

Comment: @Okazari while your answer does work, it is heavily reliant on having the correct naming convention for the `id` attribute of the divs. This will make maintenance a pain, and will lead to errors. The method above is completely agnostic of attributes and means addition/removal/re-ordering is a much simpler task.

Comment: Yup, i guess, just saying that mine worked ... But anyway nice update ! :) I learn some things there.

Comment: IGNORE THAT last comment - it's me!  Works an absolute treat!

Answer (score 2):

First, you have to give all those pages a class, lets say `page`.
Then you add a handler to the buttons:

```
$('.button_prev').click(function(e){
    var block   = $('.page:visible'),
        prev    = block.prev();
    if (prev.length) {
        prev.show();
        block.hide()
    }
});

$('.button_next').click(function(e){
    var block   = $('.page:visible'),
        next    = block.next();
    if (next.length) {
        next.show();
        block.hide()
    }
});
```

Comment: yeah, this one looks really great and all way better than mine !

Answer (score 1):

Hmmm, finishing it and seing other reponse, mine feel maybe a little weird

```
$(document).ready(function() {

//Your first page
var curPage = 1;

//your number of pages
var nbPage = 3;

$("#page2").hide();
$("#page3").hide();
$("#next").click(function(event){
    if (curPage+1 <= nbPage) curPage += 1;
    for(var i = 1; i<=3; i++){
        if (i == curPage) $("#page"+curPage).show();
        else $("#page"+i).hide();
    }
});
$("#back").click(function(event){
    if (curPage-1 >= 1) curPage -= 1;
    for(var i = 1; i<=3; i++){
         if (i == curPage) $("#page"+curPage).show();
        else $("#page"+i).hide();
    }
});
});
```

Here is the HTML.

```
<div id="page1">
   Some content
</div>

<div id="page2">
    More content
</div>

<div id="page3">
    Even more content
</div>

<button id="back">back</button>
<button id="next">next</button>
```

You can check this working demo : 
http://jsfiddle.net/kJ45a/2/

(And to the others, feel free to feedback if this way is not a good one)

Comment: That works a treat and also works when adding further `DIV`'s - just adjust the number of pages, hide the divs on load and increase the number in the code to whatever the number of pages.  Perfect.

Comment: not perfect ! Juste a way to make it work ... But looks weird finaly, Rory explained why ! Thx to him.

Comment: Appreciate you taking the time Okazari to respond.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You could use jQuery (http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/) to change the class of the element(s) you want to toggle and, in your css file, have those classes use the appropriate value for 'display' http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_display.asp

Answer (score 0):

You are going to need to bind the `click()` event to the buttons at the bottom of your page. Since you did not list them in the markup, then I will I will guess they are something like this:

Markup:

```
<button class="back">Back</button>
<button class="continue">Continue</button>
```

Now you will need the actual bindings in jQuery for when the user clicks the buttons, like this:

JavaScript:

```
$('.continue').click(function() {
    // Logic goes here for what should happen when user clicks Continue button
});

$('.back').click(function() {
    // Logic goes here for what should happen when user clicks Back button
});
```

While I know you are not doing a slideshow with images, your navigation most closely resembles a slideshow, so checkout this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/iamacatperson/hHnX5/)

Answer (score 0):

This is a basic example that i made:

JQuery Part:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$("#page2").css('visibility', 'hidden');
$("#page3").css('visibility', 'hidden');

$("#continue").click(function(){
  $("#page1").css('visibility', 'hidden');
  $("#page2").css('visibility', 'visible');
});

$("#back").click(function(){

  $("#page1").css('visibility', 'visible');
  $("#page2").css('visibility', 'hidden');

});

});
```

HTML Part:

```
<div id="page1">
Some content
</div>

<div id="page2">
More content
</div>

<div id="page3">
Even more content
</div>
<input type="button" id="continue" value="continue" />
<br/>
<input type="button" id="back" value="back" />
```

PS: See the working fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/UKnrE/1/